# Jasmine: Ignoring page redirects in tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a Javascript set up that is similar to this:

```
function a()
{
    // some logic...
    b();
};

function b()
{
    window.location = "anotherPage"
};
```

In my Jasmine test, I want to test `a()`, but I don't want the redirect to occur.

I tried:

```
spyOn(instance, 'b').andCallFake(function() { });
```

but that still is causing a redirect. Perhaps because `a()` is calling `b()` and not Jasmine calling `b()`.

Comment: Is it really instance method? It seems `b()` function is simply accesible in the scope so `a()` can call it. But `spyOn` allows you to stub function asigned to some object. Could you give us more info about your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just create spy **b** function in test.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mind elaborating a bit? I don't completely understand what you mean.

Comment: window.b = jasmine.createSpy('b');

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats instance in your case. Assuming function b is in global context aka. window, create the spy like this:

```
spyOn(window, 'b');
```